# How to insert a file g.resources into an Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, .net-assembly, ildasm

I need to modify an assembly changing one resource. I've already extracted the resource and modified it but now I cannot find the way to embed it again into the assembly. I've tried with ildasm but seems like it wants a .res resource file and I just have a xxx.g.resources file.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is just an idea: Maybe you could to create a new assembly where you could to include the new resources, and also the other "things" that you do not modified. Maybe you can extract this other "things" in the same way you extract the resources...

Comment: Could be a way, but you know ... decompilers are not perfect tools and the assembly is mid-sized so I would like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to add contents of "*.Config" file to ".g.resources" file is by changing "Build Action" property value of config file to "Resource".

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is not related at all with what I was asking got.

Comment: Understood. But, doing exactly this resolved the issue I was having with my client's existing application, which at run time reads from "<assembly>.g.resources" file and uses its contents. So, I thought posting it here may help someone.